# Unable to evaluate action commerce_shipping_service_rate_order

Tags: 7, commerce, entities

Right now, I am using Drupal 7.59, PHP 7.0.30, Commerce shipping 7.x-2.2, Commerce UPS 7.x-2.0 and Entity API 7.x-1.6. when I take an order through to checkout and then return back to the cart page. The error has occurred every time I went to checkout page again.

Here is the log I found in the report:
[image]
When I click "edit configuration", it directs me to the UPS rate rules, for example, the "Rate UPS Standard" rule.
[image]

Does anyone have any idea about this issue?

---

**Edit**

Here is the shipping_service callback in template.php file:

```
$form['commerce_shipping']['recalculate']['#ajax']['callback'] = 'custom_html_commerce_shipping_recalculate_services_refresh2';
dpm($form['commerce_shipping']['shipping_service']);
$form['commerce_shipping']['shipping_service']['#ajax']['callback'] = 'custom_html_shipping_pane_service_details_refresh';
dpm($form['commerce_shipping']['shipping_service']);
```

Here are my custom AJAX functions:

```
function custom_html_commerce_shipping_recalculate_services_refresh2($form, $form_state) {
  unset($form['commerce_shipping']['#attributes']['disable']);
  global $user;
  $orderid = $form_state['order']->order_number;

  // Load up to date order
  $order = commerce_order_load($orderid);

  //store shipping profile
  if (isset($order->commerce_customer_shipping[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['profile_id'])) {
    $profile_shipping = commerce_customer_profile_load($order->commerce_customer_shipping[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['profile_id']);
  } else {
    $profile_shipping = commerce_customer_profile_new('shipping', $user->uid);
  }
  if (isset($order->commerce_customer_billing[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['profile_id'])) {
    $profile_billing = commerce_customer_profile_load($order->commerce_customer_billing[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['profile_id']);
  } else {
    $profile_billing = commerce_customer_profile_new('billing', $user->uid);
  }

  $profile_shipping->commerce_customer_address = array(
    LANGUAGE_NONE => array(
      0 => array(
        'country' => $form_state['values']['customer_profile_shipping']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['country'],
        'administrative_area' => $form_state['values']['customer_profile_shipping']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['administrative_area'],
        'postal_code' => $form_state['values']['customer_profile_shipping']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['postal_code'],
        'locality' => $form_state['values']['customer_profile_shipping']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['locality'],
        'thoroughfare' => $form_state['values']['customer_profile_shipping']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['thoroughfare'],
        'premise' => $form_state['values']['customer_profile_shipping']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['premise'],
        'organisation_name' => $form_state['values']['customer_profile_shipping']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['organisation_name'],
        'name_line' => $form_state['values']['customer_profile_shipping']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['first_name'].' '.$form_state['values']['customer_profile_shipping']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['last_name'],
        'first_name' => $form_state['values']['customer_profile_shipping']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['first_name'],
        'last_name' => $form_state['values']['customer_profile_shipping']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['last_name'],
      ),
    ));

    $profile_billing->commerce_customer_address = array(
    LANGUAGE_NONE => array(
      0 => array(
        'country' => $form_state['values']['customer_profile_billing']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['country'],
        'administrative_area' => $form_state['values']['customer_profile_billing']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['administrative_area'],
        'postal_code' => $form_state['values']['customer_profile_billing']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['postal_code'],
        'locality' => $form_state['values']['customer_profile_billing']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['locality'],
        'thoroughfare' => $form_state['values']['customer_profile_billing']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['thoroughfare'],
        'premise' => $form_state['values']['customer_profile_billing']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['premise'],
        'organisation_name' => $form_state['values']['customer_profile_billing']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['organisation_name'],
        'name_line' => $form_state['values']['customer_profile_billing']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['first_name'].' '.$form_state['values']['customer_profile_billing']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['last_name'],
        'first_name' => $form_state['values']['customer_profile_billing']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['first_name'],
        'last_name' => $form_state['values']['customer_profile_billing']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['last_name'],
      ),
    ));
    commerce_customer_profile_save($profile_billing);
    commerce_customer_profile_save($profile_shipping);
    $order->commerce_customer_shipping[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['profile_id'] = $profile_shipping->profile_id;
    $order->commerce_customer_billing[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['profile_id'] = $profile_billing->profile_id;
    commerce_order_save($order);

    $commands = custom_html_shipping_pane_service_details_refresh($form, $form_state, '', $order);

    // Update shipping form
    $commands[] = $form['commerce_shipping'];
    $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('#commerce-shipping-service-ajax-wrapper', render($form['commerce_shipping']));

    // Update checkout cart review
    list($view_id, $display_id) = explode('|', variable_get('commerce_cart_contents_pane_view', 'commerce_cart_summary|default'));
    $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('.view-commerce-cart-summary', commerce_embed_view($view_id, $display_id, array($order->order_id)));

    return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
}

function custom_html_shipping_pane_service_details_refresh($form, &$form_state, $checkout_pane, $order)
{
    // Get order from form
    list($order, $checkout_pane) = $form_state['build_info']['args'];

    // Load up to date order
    $order = commerce_order_load($order->order_id);

    // Get selected
    $service_name = $form['commerce_shipping']['shipping_service']['#value'];
    if(!$form['commerce_shipping']['shipping_service']['#value']){
        $service_name = $form['commerce_shipping']['shipping_service']['#default_value'];
    }

    // Delete any existing shipping line items from the order.
    commerce_shipping_delete_shipping_line_items($order, TRUE);

    commerce_shipping_service_rate_order($service_name, $order);

    // Extract the unit price from the calculated rate.
    $rate_line_item = $order->shipping_rates[$service_name];
    $rate_line_item_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_line_item', $rate_line_item);
    $unit_price = $rate_line_item_wrapper->commerce_unit_price->value();

    // Create a new shipping line item with the calculated rate from the form.
    $line_item = commerce_shipping_line_item_new($service_name, $unit_price, $order->order_id, $rate_line_item->data, $rate_line_item->type);

    // Save and add the line item to the order.
    $new_line_item = commerce_shipping_add_shipping_line_item($line_item, $order, TRUE);

    commerce_order_save($order);

    // Update shipping form
    $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('#' . $form['commerce_shipping']['service_details']['#id'], render($form['commerce_shipping']['service_details']));

    // Update checkout cart review
    list($view_id, $display_id) = explode('|', variable_get('commerce_cart_contents_pane_view', 'commerce_cart_summary|default'));
    $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('.view-commerce-cart-summary', commerce_embed_view($view_id, $display_id, array($order->order_id)));

    return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
}
```

Comment: Do you experience the problem in PHP 5.6?

Comment: @RyanSzrama I have this issue in both PHP 5.6 and PHP 7.0

Comment: Got it, just wanted to rule that out. Unfortunately there isn't enough information here to diagnose the issue. We would need to see step-by-step instructions to reproduce this with the latest releases of the relevant modules on drupal.org. My guess is that for some reason the order object passed in to the action is malformed, but you'd need to check your PHP error logs to see if it gives you any more info. Beyond that you'd need to put debug messages into the action itself.

Comment: @RyanSzrama Thank you for your suggestion. I tried to print the result of `$form['commerce_shipping']['shipping_service']`. When I reloaded the checkout page, all the shipping options include UPS methods are listed under `shipping_service` correctly. But after I selected an option, all UPS shipping methods were disappeared from my `$form['commerce_shipping']['shipping_service']` list. Do you have any idea why it happens? I will add my custom code in the question immediately.

Comment: It sounds like it could be an old issue we've seen with the checkout form losing context information during Ajax operations. I can't remember where all the related issues are, but I know we talked in this thread about shipping service recalculation failing: https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/1804592#comment-12344644

Double check to make sure you're on Commerce 1.14 (the latest version). If so, then we'll need to search the Commerce and Commerce Shipping queues for other issues to get into.

Comment: @RyanSzrama Thank you very much. I updated my Commerce module to 1.14 and the error disappeared. But I got a new error every time I tried to call the ajax function to get the shipping list for a new order. Here is my error message: `EntityMetadataWrapperException: Missing data values on type "commerce_line_item" property "commerce_unit_price" with ID "false" from custom_html_shipping_pane_service_details_refresh in sites/all/modules/custom_html/custom_html.module in EntityMetadataWrapper->value() (line 100 of sites/all/modules/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).`